# Is there a field of music integrated with computer science?

Tags: computer, education

Three years ago, I received my Bachelor of Computer Science at one of the best universities in Iran. Since then, I led an artificial intelligence team for providing Persian OCR software.

In addition, since I was a child, I was deeply in love with music, especially in playing piano and music production. Now I am a piano and violin player and I'm enthusiastic to further my education with a master's degree, in a field which integrates Computer Science and Music.

However, I don’t want to apply for a field in which I sometimes just encounter music terminology. I want to get involved with music and use my background in either computer science or artificial intelligence.  Could you help me find such a field?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking if there is a master's program at some university that combines computer science and music? If that is your actual question, then you should edit what you wrote to clearly state that. Also I suspect the answer is "no", but most masters degree programs in any field require you to concentrate on some area. So you could get a masters in CS with a concentration in music, dsp, etc.

Comment: I've clarified the question a bit and removed a little (your resume) that would make it too narrow -- I think there's a good core question here and we want to make sure it's applicable to others who have the same goal.

Comment: If you're looking from an educational perspective, this might be a good starting point  https://ccrma.stanford.edu/

If you're looking for positions, you could start with the DAW & Notation software makers.   Both those would probably appreciate some OCR and AI experience.

Comment: Ninja'd by @Greg. Stanford's Center for Computer Research in Music and Acoustics has been doing this for a long time, offers post-grad degrees.

Answer (score 3):

There is the field of [Computer Music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_music) and [Sound and music computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_and_music_computing) which seem related to the background you have. For computer music, you can even find several reputable journals (i.e [MIT](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/cmj)) so you can use that as a starting point to find any other related fields.

Answer (score 2):

Music OCR is an ongoing issue.  Converting audio into symbolic information is going to turn into one well-funded field of research because of every bit of humanly recognizable musical information getting copyrighted and sued over for hundreds of years.  Also search engines and electronic assistants are going to converge and provide new challenges for searching for music based on awful attempts to hum/sing a few bars.

So there is a lot of cash floating around in "new technology" areas connected with your interests.  You just have to figure out where it currently clots and go after it.

Comment: Audiveris is an open source OCR for music.   MuseScore uses it for it's OCR service (or at least it used to.. not sure of the current state).